# Exception : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: invalid column name id

Tags: java, hibernate-native-query

when I ty to run this query

```
@Query(value = "select TOP(10) noleggi.id_libro, count(*) as occ from noleggi " +
            "group by noleggi.id_libro " +
            "order by occ desc",
    nativeQuery=true)

    List<Noleggio> findTop10();
```

Hibernate shows this error :

> select TOP(10) noleggi.id_libro, count(*) as occ from noleggi group by
>   noleggi.id_libro order by occ desc 2020-01-12 15:07:08.444  WARN 12316
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093 2020-01-12 15:07:08.444 ERROR 12316 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : invalid
>   column name id.

I don't use id, what do it means that?

Comment: Your method is supposed to return a List<Noleggio>. A Noleggio, I guess, has an ID. But your query doesn't return any ID. Use the correct return type. Your query actually returns a List<Object[]>. So that's what the return type should be.

Comment: can you please describe table and Noleggio  class

Comment: my table noleggi has id PK, id_libro and user_id FK and my noleggio Class has    public class Noleggio {
 
 private Long id;
 
 

 private LocalDate inizioPrestito;
 
 private LocalDate finePrestito;
 

 @JoinColumn(name = "id_utente")
 private Utente utente;
 

 @JoinColumn(name = "id_libro")
 private Libro libro;